# Safari not open iOS Apps in iOS 9

Tags: ios, safari, redirect, ios9, url-scheme

I Have a url sending to email and if the user hit that link it opens the app if it's installed, and it was working fine in iOS 8, since i switched to iOS 9 the redirection to the application not working any more, I tried to add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" array and add my url schemes in it, but i did not work too. So, what did it miss ?

Comment: Can you show your URL and the XML from the application .plist file for key **<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>** ?
Right click on *.plist  and Open As -> Source Code

Comment: @IurieManea that works from app to app, i asked about from safari to app, by the way check my answer down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a fix in javascript code that make a redirection to url that open my application.

I was create an iframe that hold a url src object for the redirect url. I removed that iframe and replaced it with that line window.location = "url", that's it and every thing work perfectly fine and safari now redirected me again to my application but this time with one more step is it shows up a message for the user that ensure he want to goto the application.

So, if any one faced that problem with redirection again, check the redirection code javascript and remove the iframe and replaced it with window.location

Comment: @Desco check this solution out

Comment: What if the user that is visiting your mobile website doesn't have the app installed? Safari opens up an error box. Not good.

Comment: @tommy.bonderenka yea, it's not good in that case, so you should add a view has a button in case the website opens form mobile device says open the app or continue in app maybe. and it redirect the user to the app with that way, but my case was different because i do not have a website for the users to browse. So, it works with me in that way.

Comment: i have been using window.location. Its working fine with iOS below 9.0 but on 9.0 it shows error : invalid address

Comment: @Swati make sure that the url redirection in your address matches the url scheme in url types properties in info.plist file in your iOS application.

Answer (score 4):

With iOS9, Apple is changing a few things concerning URL schemes. http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes is an article about those changes.

Basically, you now have to register all URL schemes that are supported by your app in your .plist file.

Comment: I read that, he is talking about canOpenURL and openURL methods, and i'm talking about a link open in safari and its redirected me to my app, the link of course not using one of these method.

Answer (score 0):

This is being discussed on Apple's support forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7221842

My company's got an open ticket with Apple support for this problem.

Unfortunately, no resolution yet.